# Compare arrays for matching elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have two arrays,

arr1 contains a list of ids:

```
var arr1 = new Array(1,2,3);
```

arr2 contains a list of objects having id´s matching the ids i arr1

```
 var2 = [
{id:1,
name: "bob"},
{id:2,
name:"Moore"}
]
```

How can I 'loop' these arrays against each other and have some code happening when a match is found?

Comment: Start from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: What do you want to do when they're found? Do you want a collection of all the items from var2 that match against the ids in arr1? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: `var2` array has some invalid values. Assuming name's are strings..

Comment: Yes, I want a Collection of all the objects that have the id´s from arr1. 
Well, I found an example that used 
var a=[1,2,3,4];
if ( 2 in a ) alert("exist");
Which seems to do what I want, But this only works with a hardcoded value. I need too loop somehow.

Comment: @Alex, yes...this is not my actual Array, i just used this as an example and forgot the "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through id array checking each one against object array. Also some invalid values in object array I fixed below.

```
var arr1 = new Array(1,2,3);
var arr2 = [
    {
        id:1,
        name: 'bob'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name: 'moore'
    }
];

var results = [];
var index = 0, length = arr1.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    var subIndex = 0, subLength = arr2.length;
    for ( ; subIndex < subLength; subIndex++) {
        if (arr1[index] == arr2[subIndex].id) {
            results.push(arr2[subIndex]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. I actually combined @tymeJV with this answer beacuse this one also pushes the result into an Array. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `filter` if I needed the matches.

```
var matches = arr2.filter(function (item) {
  return arr1.indexOf(item.id) > -1;
});
```

Then I'd do what I need to with `matches`.

If I just needed to see if one existed I'd use `some`.

```
var hasMatch = arr2.some(function (item) {
  return arr1.indexOf(item.id) > -1;
});

if (hasMatch) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an "Associative Array"

```
   for(var i = 0;i<var2.length;i++){
     if(var2[var1[i]]){
       //do some mother trucking code
     }
   }
```

i was thinking something else actually. why not just double for loop?

```
for(var i = 0;i<arr1.length;i++){ for(var j = 0;j<var2.length;j++){ if(arr1[i] === var2[j].id){ //do stuff } } }
```

Comment: i was thinking something else actually. 

why not just double for loop?

for(var i = 0;i<arr1.length;i++){
for(var j = 0;j<var2.length;j++){
if(arr1[i] === var2[j].id){
//do stuff
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Look, check, logic:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < var2.length; j++) {
        if (arr1[i] == var2[j].id) {
            //logic for match
        }
    }
}
```